# Tables versioning - DML and DDL tracking changes and roll back to previous version

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, versioning

I have to build a model where i am tracking DDL and DML changes and have possibility to go to previous version.

Goal to achive:
1. Customer uses some version
2. User knows what it is
3. User makes changes and he knows what he is changing.
4. User releases new version and knows what it is.

General goal: have different versions/states of tables and have possibility to go back to previous version and to not deleting data (preserving existing ones).

I was thinking to create:
1. snapshosts for each version
2. Restore snapshots if necessarry with ddl and dml changes
3. track all changes using event triggers

Problem is that only one version of snapshot can be used in the same time. 
Tables do not have the same problem, by multiple copies of tables at the same time you can consume number of versions, it is matter of querying,
I am using postgresql database but most of functions in ms sql server are similar.

Please help, maybe some of you had similar problem or have the idea how to solve it? 
Best,
Jacek

Comment: This makes no sense at all.

Comment: I've removed the sql-server tag as you mentioned you are not using sql-server

Comment: @Sean Lange why not?